# React Router Dom, redirection happens before the code inside useEffect gets executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am attempting to use React's `useEffect` hook to run a fetch command and store the result in state. I would then like to use that state value to conditionally render a React Route component. I am having trouble setting the value of that variable in state before the component runs the conditional statement and returns the Route component.

Express code:

```
app.post('/refresh_token_from_db', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(true)
})
```

ProtectedRoutes:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function ProtectedRoutes() {
    const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean>(false);

    // Data does't start loading
    // until *after* component is mounted
    useEffect(() => {
        const go = async () => {
            await fetch('/refresh_token_from_db', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'same-origin',
                redirect: 'follow',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Should run 1st", data);
                setToken(data)
            })
        }
        go()
    }, []);

    console.log("Should run 2nd", token);
    return (
        token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
    );
}

export default ProtectedRoutes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Your initial `token` state masks, or matches, the "unauthenticated" state and this is why the `Navigate` component is rendered on the initial render cycle and navigates to the login route.

## Solution

Don't use the same initial state as either the "authenticated" or "unauthenticated" state values. Use this "indeterminant" state value to conditionally render null or some loading indicator. Also, don't mix `async/await` with Promise chains, it's considered anti-pattern. Keep in mind that `fetch` ***can*** return rejected Promises and you should handle these accordingly.

Example:

```
function ProtectedRoutes() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean | undefined>(); // <-- initially undefined

  // Data does't start loading
  // until *after* component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    const go = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/refresh_token_from_db', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'same-origin',
          redirect: 'follow',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setToken(data);
      } catch(error) {
        // catch/handle any errors
        // set unauthenticated status
        setToken(false);
      }
    };

    go();
  }, []);

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc...
  }

  return token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the data as well as executing the callback of an `useEffect` and mutating the `state` in React are asynchronous tasks. Which means this code:

```
return (
   token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
);
```

might run before this one `setToken(data)` inside your `useEffect`, and which is happening to cause that earlier redirection. Sadly you cannot or very hardly dictate the order of execution here. One workaround is to use an additional sate, I called it `checking`, and show  a `Loader` while the code inside `useEffect` is being executed, like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ProtectedRoutes() {
    const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [checking, setIsChecking] = useState<boolean>(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const go = () => {
            fetch('/refresh_token_from_db', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'same-origin',
                redirect: 'follow',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setToken(data)
                setIsChecking(false)
            })
        }
        go()
    }, []);

    if(checking) return <p>Loading...</p>

    return (
        token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
    );
}
```